# How can we implement excel.interop services in azure?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

We have a web application that we have hosted as an app service in Azure.In this we are using excel.interop services. Would like to know whether we will we able to retain the same code in the application after hosting it on azure.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, if we want to use `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel`, we should install **MS office**. But it seems that Azure App Service does not support it.

I recommend two workarounds:

1. Use Azure VM to host the application and install MS office on the Azure VM, you refer to this [article](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/8bc2b37a-4d37-4e3f-bac1-8db44bf007b8/installing-office-clients-excel-word-or-visio-on-azure-vm?forum=WAVirtualMachinesforWindows).
2. Instead of `excel.interop`, use OpenXML to do it, you could refer to this [article](https://debugmode.net/2011/08/28/creating-and-updating-excel-file-in-windows-azure-web-role-using-open-xml-sdk/).

Hope it helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can "containerize" your application as a container and run it in App Service as a Windows Container App (this feature is still in preview).

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-the-public-preview-of-windows-container-support-in-azure-app-service/

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/windows-server-2019-support-added-to-public-preview-of-windows-container-support/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-get-started-windows-container

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-windows-containers-custom-fonts

Comment: Have anyone tried this? does it work?